# Layout with continuous background images, but centred content?

Tags: css, html, layout

I am trying to work out how I would go about creating a website that has 3 separate 'layers' (top navigation, then content, then footer) each with a different background image, that tiles to 100% width... but I want my content to be centred (as if the containing divs had margin: 0 auto applied).

So far I have been attempting to create divs just for the background images, and then absolutely positioning my content divs, but allowing them to automatically centre.

But of corse, I am taking elements out of the 'flow' of the document there, and so my background image divs end up stacking up against each other.

This is really tough to explain so hopefully this example will help:

http://jsfiddle.net/RB46S/

As you can see, I have my blue div, where the background stretches to 100% BUT I WANT MY NAVIGATION AND A LARGE IMAGE TO CENTRE HERE.

I have my body which is green, then a hp_content div, this would be where all my content would sit, centred, the problem here is you cannot apply a margin or a padding value (i've applied them to show them not working), only a position from the top of the parent/browser, which will lead to problems when making my site responsive I believe.

Then I have my red div which is the same as the top navigation (blue) div, It has a 100% border but I want the footer stuff (twitter feed, latest blog post, and contact details) to be centred here.

Hopefully some one understands what I am trying to achieve and knows how to correctly set a page like this up, any help is much appreciated!

Jon

Comment: You donot want to set padding/margin ? But you want all your text to be horizontally centered in the page ?

Comment: Maybe this example will clarify what I am trying to achieve. - http://www.jessmarksphotography.com.au - See how there is three 'layers' of textured background images, green - dark brown - cream. but then all the content is centred, how would I go about doing so? in my example I was trying, my content starts UNDER my first band of colour (the blue div). Sorry it's really hard to explain, is that clearer? - thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok! Try structuring your HTML something like this:

```
<html>
<head></head>

<body class="index">

    <section class="top">
        <header class="content">
            <nav>
                <ul id="">
                    <li><a href="" id="">link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" id="">link 2</a></li>  
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </section>

    <section class="main">
        <div class="content">
            <h2>Whatever</h2>
            <div class="something">This is something else</div>
        </div>        
    </section>

    <section class="footer">
        <footer class="content">
            Footer content
        </footer>
    </section>

</body>
</html>​
```

Then some CSS like:

```
body, html{    
    width:100%;   
}

body {
    background: green;
}

body > section{
    width:100%;
}

/* this style will set all the section .content(s) to be 400px wide */
body > section > .content{
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:400px;    
}

section.top {
    height: 510px;
    background: blue;
}

/* if you want to individually change widths for each section, do something like this:*/

section.top .content{
    width:100%;
}    

/* or not! */

section.main {
    height:200px;
}

section.footer {
    height: 400px;
    background: red;
}
```

Play around: http://jsfiddle.net/FC2Ea/

So for each site section, you'd have a container for all of that section's content with an easy-to-remember class name like ".content". You can set all the content to the same width, or each section's content to different widths depending what you're going for. Either way, the sections will occupy 100% of the browser's width. Good luck! :)

​

Comment: This is extremely helpful to me, thank you, marked as the correct answer as it answers the question perfectly. Thanks again! - And just to point out there is a missing '=' on the <section class="main"> if you'd like to edit it in so others don't get confused as to why the CSS cannot style that element!

Answer (score 0):

If you add another Div within your each main Div and use style as

```
<div style="Width: 80%; float:right; margin-right: 150px;">
```

I guess that might help to an extent ?

```
<div class="top_shade">  
    <div style="Width: 80%; float:right; margin-right: 150px;">      
    <header>
                <nav>
                    <ul id="">
                        <li><a href="" id=""></a></li>
                        <li><a href="" id=""></a></li>
                        <li><a href="" id=""></a></li>
                        <li><a href="" id=""></a></li>
                        <li><a href="" id=""></a></li>     
                    </ul>
                </nav>
    </header>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work on the body section (middle layer) because on that layer there is no containing div, only the body. So it ends up calculating the margins against the body (side of the browser window) and not centring the content. Thanks for the suggestion though